# Gradle multi-module tests falling

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have following project structure:

```
root
├── common
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── build.gradle
├── moduleA
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── build.gradle
├── moduleB
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── build.gradle
└── build.gradle
```

**:moduleA** and **:moduleB** are *independent* applications, which are using dependencies from **:common**.

**:moduleA** and **:moduleB** are also Spring Boot applications, **:common** module has a few Spring JPA repositories which are used in applications.

When I try to run tests (`gradlew clean test`) I got following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> foo.bar.project.moduleA.repository.SomeRepository
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

Additionaly when I build (`gradlew clean build -x test`) applications (**:moduleA** and **:moduleB**) are created successfully and works like a charm, without any problems!

Run test from IDE (InteliJ) also works.

root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.4.2'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

allprojects {
    group = 'foo.bar.project'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'java-test-fixtures'

    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility = 11
        targetCompatibility = 11
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")

        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        // removed rest of dependencies for brevit
}
```

**:common** `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    enabled = true
    archiveBaseName = 'project-common'
}

bootJar.enabled = false

distTar.enabled = false
distZip.enabled = false
bootDistZip.enabled = false

startScripts.enabled = false
bootStartScripts.enabled = false

dependencies {
    testFixturesImplementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre'
    // removed rest of dependencies for brevity
}
```

**:moduleA** `build.gradle`:

```
ext['rest-assured.version'] = '4.2.0'

application {
    mainClassName = 'foo.bar.project.moduleA.Application'
    applicationName = 'project-module-a'
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = application.mainClassName
    archiveClassifier = 'boot'
    archiveVersion = '0.1.0'
}

distTar.enabled = false
distZip.enabled = false
bootDistZip.enabled = false

startScripts.enabled = false
bootStartScripts.enabled = false

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":common")))
}
```

**:moduleB** `build.gradle`:

```
application {
    mainClassName = 'foo.bar.project.moduleB.Application'
    applicationName = 'project-module-b'
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = application.mainClassName
    archiveClassifier = 'boot'
    archiveVersion = '0.1.0'
}

distTar.enabled = false
distZip.enabled = false
bootDistZip.enabled = false

startScripts.enabled = false
bootStartScripts.enabled = false

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')

    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":common")))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely certain but when I've had this sort of problem in the past its because I was trying to share classes from `moduleA` in `moduleB`... but as they're spring boot applications, they're packaged differently and this is impossible.

What I can say looking at the above is you've set the root project `build.gradle` to apply the plugin `application`. The root project will not be an application and subprojects are springboot applications, so this can be removed entirely. You're essentially specifying two lots of "mainClass" - one for the application plugin inherited from the root project, and another for the springboot application plugin - applied at root - but the `:common` project is not a springboot application.. so it needs pushing down the module hierarchy to the modules which are actually springboot applications, and not applied at the root where it will be inherited by all applications.

If you move the plugins to the relevant modules that need them, you'll find the `build.gralde`s will become cleaner as you won't have to disable unused plugins in the sub-`build.gradle` definitions.

Comment: Indeed, when I moved `application` plugin to **:moduleA** and **:moduleB**, **:common** module is clearer, but this not solve problem with error on running tests.

Comment: you should do the same for the springboot plugin (and other plugins where possible). You also don't need the java plugin. Its automatically there by default (implicit) because you've included the springboot plugin.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Same results  :( I left `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin for dependency management purposes and `java`, `java-library` and `java-test-fixtures` in the root `build.gradle`. But what is weird, the problem is to run test (load classes) from e.g: **:moduleA** in **:moduleA**.

Comment: Another suggestion: if you want to use `testFixtures` in `moduleA` and `moduleB`, extract that test code to a `src/main/java` in a newly named module, `test-fixtures`. This way you can just import the project. When you import a module in gradle, you only import from src/main/java, test code is not included.

Comment: Try removing all plugins and associated code, then add them back in one by one and test.. Test the code works each time. Incremental development will help you identify where the problem is

Comment: Bingo @Rob Evans! Two things. Firstly moved `textFixtures` gradle feature to module `test-fixture`, and import in the e.g. **:moduleA** as `testImplementation`. Secondly removed `testFixtures` plugin at all. That seems to be a main culprit. Although it seems to work, it's intresting why this `testFixtures` causes a problem.